# How to make font-face work with all letters

Tags: css, font-face

I am hoping this is a CSS clash some place that I am missing, but the site is here:
https://bbking2019.wpengine.com/

The code is here:

```
/*Set the font face for h3*/
@font-face {
  font-family: carrotflower;
  src: url('/wp-content/uploads/fonts/Carrotflower.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('/wp-content/uploads/fonts/Carrotflower.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/wp-content/uploads/fonts/Carrotflower.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('/wp-content/uploads/fonts/Carrotflower.ttf') format('truetype');
}

h3{
    font-family: carrotflower !important;
}
```

This works on all the letters EXCEPT the capital V in Visitor Testimonials - when editing in the browser tools a lowercase v works perfectly with the font.

Any ideas on how to make the capital V work would be fantastic.

Thanks in advance!

An example can be messed with here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_font-face_rule

Just change out the url for the woff file to https://bbking2019.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/fonts/Carrotflower.woff

Then in the type some text and add a v and a V - the capital is still not working.

Comment: The capital V in Visitor Testimonials works fine for me. I'm on Windows10 Edge what browser/OS are you using?

Comment: OP is right, on Windows Edge and Firefox both browsers show a regular "V" (none script like) Arial or whatever is set as default font in the browser. When changed to "v" font family "carrotflower" (script like) is shown. Odd.... Omission in the font file character table? Have you tried with a simple test page? Please post a [reprex] with access to the "carrotflower" font... BTW, those three portrait images load way too slow... Quarter of the animation delay would suffice.

Comment: Thanks @RenevanderLende - I have added a place for a working example - it may be missing the V after testing there. And I did not build the site, they asked me to look at other items haha! But I agree, slider is too slow

Comment: The "V" is not implemented in the font, I opened the TTF version and you can see that [some letter are different](https://i.ibb.co/ZV9SdCy/font.png)

Comment: Workaround the error and use `<span L>V</span>` with CSS `[L] { font-size: 1.125em }`  or some appropriate size for the unsupported characters. Maybe that yields a satisfactory result. Or for all capitals to stay consistent. Or use a lookalike font family and save yourself the trouble, seems a legit reason enough. Thanks to @Joel for the comparison.... Oh, and nag with the font creator for their omissions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some digging from Rene van der Lende and Joel, indeed the V was/is not implemented in the font table. We are going to work around it with a similar font and contact the creator.

Thanks everyone for your efforts.